# Clean Windows 7 temporary Internet files

Tags: windows-7, temporary-files

I use Internet Explorer 9's "Delete temp Internet files" option, and it does delete files, but there is a hidden system folder at C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5 with thousands of files that are untouched by this process.

Diskcleanup is no help either.

I've also used some popular temporary file cleaners like ATF that also ignore these files.

How do I really zap ALL the temporary files (Internet Explorer or otherwise) on post-Windows Vista computers?

Comment: Can you delete it yourself, manually? I usually use CCleaner for cleaning, but **be careful** with it. Don't delete anything you don't want to delete.

Comment: @RogUE The OP states that Disk Cleanup did not help.

Comment: @RogUE I'm just pointing out what the OP has already stated *Diskcleanup is no help either*. To me, that means the OP already tried what you suggested in your comment. I'm not debating if it works or not. If you have an answer for the question, please post it below.

Comment: @CharlieRB Didn't see the line **Diskcleanup is no help either**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That folder is the System user's profile folder.

Perhaps check out this SU question: [What is System32\config\systemprofile?](https://superuser.com/questions/598601/what-is-system32-config-systemprofile)

Most cleaning apps (all, AFAIK) won't touch it, since it's technically "system" files.  Just manually delete everything in that folder, and/or schedule a regular task to do it for you.

Comment: Sure, but then technically (in my mind anyway) all temp files are system files; there not for me, they belong to the system for it's use.  If it's OK for me to delete them manually then why doesn't diskcleanup or IE 'remove temp files' do it (rhetorical question)? These temp files seem to be anything but temporary.

Comment: IE's option only removes the Temp files for the current user profile.  Why Disk Cleanup doesn't do it is a question for MS. :)

Comment: Just some interesting additional info. Cleaning a win 7 box that had browser hijacks, temp folder mentioned has 6 million plus files in it!  This causes scanners, dir listings, etc, to appear to hang (as in for 24 hours) when they try to read this folder.  Using admin cmd prompt to del *.*, been running for over 24 hours, deleting at a rate of 500 files per 10 sec.